# Can the inflow of a fluid simulation be scripted to flow water at varying mass & velocity during the simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

so I'm attempting a simulation of what is essentially a tidal barrage, and convinced myself that blender would be the easiest way but I don't see a convenient way to edit the behavior of the inflow in blender? I'm trying to manage the momenta of particles being input according to data i have for a 24hr cycle. Maybe it's a hidden feature.

I may have simply chosen the wrong software, if anyone could tell me if this is beyond the capabilities of blender? or how to access the code for managing the inflow?